# Killing Apps on a jailbroken phone

Tags: ios, kill

I am trying to create an app that kills other apps on my jailbroken phone. I have tried many different kill commands but none of them seem to do the trick. I am wondering if anybody has found a kill command that works?

Comment: What have you tried? How have they failed? Are you trying to kill processes owned by different user ids?

Comment: So far I have tried system("/usr/bin/killall 'app name'");
I have also tried kill -9 Process ID. Neither of those have worked.   Yes I would like to kill processes owned by different user IDs. I would ideally like to hook a kill command up to a timer and have it continuously kill different apps. I have a list of the app names and the process IDs for all of the apps on my phone. I am just looking for a command to kill them with.

Comment: Does your code run with `root` privileges?

Comment: No it does not run with root privileges. How would I go about setting it up so that it does?

Answer (score 1):

There's a handful of ways to get `root` privileges on Unix systems; I don't know what would be most appropriate for your jail-broken iOS device, but I can at least outline what's possible on the underlying platform:

- Install your program `setuid root`:

  ```
  chown root:root /path/to/program/executable
  chmod 04755 /path/to/program/executable
  ```

  When your program runs, it will run as `root` and have the full privileges and responsibilities of `root`.
- Use a `setuid root` helper program, such as `su(1)` or `sudo(8)` to run your program as `root`:

  ```
  sudo /path/to/program/executable
  ```
- Configure the system startup tools to run your program with `root` privileges at boot time; this is much more complicated for me to describe, since system boot is extremely system dependent. Look for `/etc/inittab` or `/etc/rc*` as starting points. (Maybe iOS uses the newer [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)?)

Comment: I am sorry but this is my first year as a programmer and I really like your idea but I was wondering if you could send me a more detailed version of how to implement it into my project.

Comment: It sort of depends upon what's available on your platform; I'd really avoid running your program `setuid root` completely unless it truly needs `root` privileges all the time.